# Line chart over Column chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a column chart with multiple series. (number of series vary from 1-14). X axis is date and Y axis is count.I would like to create a line chart which gives the sum of all series count per date. I tried adding another value of count and changing the chart type to line but the line is drawn with maximum series count per date. Also the label is repeating twice for every series.
Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.
1. **Rollup your Query in SQL** - doing this will add a total value for each date as well as a total value for the entire query. Your query would look something like this:

```
select
    YourDate,
    YourSeries,
    sum(YourCount) YourCount
from YourTable
group by
    YourDate,
    YourSeries
with rollup
```

2. **Filter out the grand total** - the `with rollup` clause produces a grand total that your chart doesn't need. You can filter this out of the dataset by adding a filter expression `=IsNothing(Fields!YourDate.Value)`, datatype `Boolean`, value `=False`
3. **Set your chart values visibility** - set the column values visibility to `=IsNothing(Fields!YourSeries.Vale)` and the line chart values visibility to `=Not(IsNothing(Fields!YourSeries.Vale)`. Now, your chart and series legend will only show the daily columns and the total line.
4. **Put the total line chart on a secondary axis** This is optional, but since the date totals will be much greater than each series/date value, it will keep the columns from shrinking so small.

It should look something like this:
[image]